# Como eu faço para voltar a versões antigas no nodejs pelo npm?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Preciso ir Node.js versão 5.10.0 para poder usar o Hospedagem do firebase

Answer (score 2):

Basta

```
sudo npm cache clean -f
sudo npm install -g n
sudo n x.x.x
```

Aonde x.x.x é a versão que você quer

Fonte:https://www.abeautifulsite.net/how-to-upgrade-or-downgrade-nodejs-using-npm

Comment: Muito obrigadooo

Answer (score 0):

No Windows você pode resolver com o gerenciador de pacotes Chocolatey:

*Partindo do princípio que você tenha o [Chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/install) instalado, siga os passos abaixo:

1. No CMD como administrador, digite o comando:

   cinst nodejs.install –version [xx.xx.x] –allow-downgrade

Certifique-se de alterar xx.xx.x pelo número da versão que deseja instalar.

EX: cinst nodejs.install –version 10.16.1 –allow-downgrade

2. Feche e abra novamente o CMD ou reinicie seu computador.

Fonte: [Como substituir ou voltar para uma versão do Node.js](https://medium.com/@viniciusveigadev/como-substituir-ou-voltar-para-uma-vers%C3%A3o-do-node-js-f2aa40591036)